# ActiveAdmin expand collapse in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, activeadmin, ruby-2.1

Im using activeadmin with rails 3.2.13 and ruby 2.1.2p95 and I would like to customize the form view.

I have seen alot of different things that is possible to do, but I need to be able to expand and collapse areas. I was thinking of a togglebutton.

I have for example:

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs "Payments" do
    f.has_many :product_payments do |i|
      i.input :percent
      i.input :percent_max
    end
  end
  f.actions
end
```

For each of these "has many" I would like to be able to expand and collapse the values, in this case percent and percent_max, by pressing a button.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

what you need to do is add a button for every product_payment and write some javascript in `active_admin.js`

it will be something like this:

```ruby
form do |f|
  f.inputs "Payments" do
    f.has_many :product_payments do |i|
      button "toggle", class: 'btn-toggle', type: 'button'
      i.input :percent
      i.input :percent_max
    end
  end
  f.actions
end
```

and in `active_admin.js` add

```js
$( ".btn-toggle" ).click(function(event) {
  // find the element that you need to show/hide,
});
```

maybe you will have to use some data attr to know which button belongs to which product_payment

Comment: But when I add the line with the button, the rest of my content inside f.has_many disappears, do you have any idea why?

Comment: strange, can you try using a different element, like a `li`

Comment: If I add a `li "text"` the only output i get from the f.has_many is 8 lines of `* test`

Comment: well you can add a class to that and using css make it look like a button, if you have this in a open repo I can check if you are missing something

Comment: well i still have the same problem, the rest of the content in the f.has_many still disappears, it only the `* test`that gets written.

Comment: hey I did something similar today, and worked fine, the only thing that I added was the "type=button" attr for the button, btw I'm using rails 4.1 and master version of Active-Admin